# Shell command-line interpreter with pipeline parsing

Tags: c, parsing, shell

Like many others I've been writing a shell command-line interpreter that can do a pretty decent pipeline parsing, first it splits the command at pipeline char (|), then it splits the substring at unquoted whitespace so that a pipeline e.g.  `$ ls -a -h -l|awk'{print $3}'|sort -n` gets represented with a matrix A where `A[i][j]` is program (pipe) i and argument number j. The code produces the correct output except for quoted pipelines (e.g. `$ echo 'foo|bar'|cat` won't work) but that functionality I can add. What I want is to make the code more readable and maintainable now that it "works" (doesn't crash and makes the right output).

### main.c

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500

#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "openshell.h"
#include "errors.h"
#include "do.h"
#include "CommandEntry.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <readline/history.h>
#include <histedit.h>

#ifdef SIGDET
#if SIGDET == 1
int isSignal = 1;       /*Termination detected by signals*/
#endif
#endif
static int count = 0;
static FILE *sourcefiles[MAX_SOURCE];

/*
 * The special maximum argument value which means that there is
 * no limit to the number of arguments on the command line.
 */
#define    INFINITE_ARGS    0x7fffffff

static struct option options[] = {
        {"with_param", 1, 0, 'p'},
        {"version",    0, 0, 'v'},
        {"help",       0, 0, 'h'},
        {0,            0, 0, 0}
};
/*
 * The table of built-in commands.
 * A command is terminated wih an entry containing NULL values.
 * These commands should preferable by written in openshell
 */
static const CommandEntry commandEntryTable[] =
        {
                {
                        "checkenv", do_checkenv, 1, INFINITE_ARGS,
                        "Check environment variables",
                        ""
                },

                {
                        "editenv",  do_editenv,  3, INFINITE_ARGS,
                        "do_editenv",
                        "[txp]v arFileName fileName ..."
                },

                {
                        "cd",       do_cd,       1, 2,
                        "Change current directory",
                        "[dirName]"
                },


                {
                        "exit",     do_exit,     1, 2,
                        "Exit from shell",
                        "[exit value]"
                },


                {
                        "help",     do_help,     1, 2,
                        "Print help about a command",
                        "[word]"
                },

                {
                        "killport", do_killport, 2, INFINITE_ARGS,
                        "Send a signal to the specified process",
                        "[-sig] pid ..."
                },


                {
                        NULL,       0,           0, 0,
                        NULL,
                        NULL
                }
        };


char *concat(char *s1, char *s2) {
    char *result = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1);//+1 for the zero-terminator
    //in real code you would check for errors in malloc here
    if (result == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed!\n");
        return (char *) '0';
    }
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}

int testFn(const char *str) {
    return (str && *str && str[strlen(str) - 1] == '}') ? 1 : 0;
}

static int runCmd(const char *cmd) {
    const char *cp;
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    struct command structcommand[15];
    char **argv = 0;
    int argc = 1;
    bool pipe = false;
    char *string[75][75];
    char *pString3[40];
    char *pString2[40];
    int n = 0;
    char **ptr1;
    char string1[75];
    bool keep = false;
    char *pString1[75];
    char *pString[75];
    *pString1 = "\0";
    *pString = "\0";
    char temp[75] = {'\0'};
    int w = 0;
    bool b = false;
    int j = 0;
    int i;
    int p = 0;
    char **ptr;
    char *tmpchar;
    char *cmdtmp;
    bool b1 = false;
    char *dest;
    int y = 0;
    i = 0;
    int h = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < 75; x++) { /* for each pipeline */
        for (int c = 0; c < 75; c++) { /* for each pipeline */
            string[x][c] = '\0';
        }
    }
    if (cmd) {
        for (cp = cmd; *cp; cp++) {
            if ((*cp >= 'a') && (*cp <= 'z')) {
                continue;
            }
            if ((*cp >= 'A') && (*cp <= 'Z')) {
                continue;
            }
            if (isDecimal(*cp)) {
                continue;
            }
            if (isBlank(*cp)) {
                continue;
            }
            if ((*cp == '.') || (*cp == '/') || (*cp == '-') ||
                (*cp == '+') || (*cp == '=') || (*cp == '_') ||
                (*cp == ':') || (*cp == ',') || (*cp == '\'') ||
                (*cp == '"')) {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    if (cmd) {
        cmdtmp = malloc(sizeof(char *) * strlen(cmd) + 1);
        strcpy(cmdtmp, cmd);
        tmpchar = malloc(sizeof(char *) * strlen(cmd) + 1);
        if (tmpchar == NULL) {
            printf("Error allocating memory!\n"); /* print an error message */
            return 1; /* return with failure */
        }
        strcpy(tmpchar, cmd);
        ptr1 = str_split(pString3, cmdtmp, '|');
        if (strstr(cmd, "|") == NULL) {         /* not a pipeline */
            makeArgs(cmd, &argc, (const char ***) &argv, pipe, 0, 0);
            for (j = 0; j < argc; j++) {
                string[0][j] = argv[j];
                structcommand[i].argv = string[0]; /*process;*/
            }
            n++;
        }
        else {
            for (i = 0; *(ptr1 + i); i++) { /* tokenize the input string for each pipeline*/
                n++; /* save number of pipelines */
                int e = 0; /* a counter */
                *pString = "\0"; /* should malloc and free this? */
                strcpy(string1, *(ptr1 + i));
                if ((string1[0] != '\0') && !isspace(string1[0])) { /* this is neither the end nor a new argument */
                    ptr = str_split(pString2, *(&string1), ' '); /* split the string at the arguments */
                    h = 0;
                    for (j = 0; *(ptr + j); j++) { /* step through the arguments */
                        /* the pipeline is in cmdtmp and the argument/program is in ptr[i] */
                        if (ptr + j && !b && strstr(*(ptr + j), "'")) {
                            b = true;
                            strcpy(temp, *(ptr + j));
                            if (y < 1) {
                                y++;
                            }
                        }
                        while (b) {
                            if (*(ptr + j) && strstr(*(ptr + j), "'")) { /* end of quote */
                                b = false;
                                if (y < 1) {
                                    string[i][j] = strcpy(temp, *(ptr + j));
                                }
                                y = 0;
                            }
                            else if (*(ptr + j)) { /* read until end of quote */
                                string[i][j] = temp;
                                continue;
                            } else {
                                b = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (ptr + j) {
                            if (*(ptr + j)[0] == '{') {
                                keep = true;
                            }
                            if (testFn(*(ptr + j))) { /* test for last char */
                                string[i][j - p] = concat(*pString1, *(ptr + j));
                                keep = false;
                                free(*pString1);
                                goto mylabel;
                            }
                            if (keep) {
                                *pString1 = concat(*pString1, *(ptr + j));
                                *pString1 = concat(*pString1, " ");
                                p++;
                            } else {
                                strcpy(temp, *(ptr + j));
                                b1 = false;
                                int q = j;
                                for (e = 0; *(ptr + q + e); e++) { /* step through the string */
                                    b1 = true;
                                    if (*(ptr + e + q)) {
                                        *pString = concat(*pString, *(ptr + e + q));
                                        *pString = concat(*pString, " ");
                                    }
                                    j = e;
                                }
                                if (makeArgs(*pString, &argc, (const char ***) &argv, pipe, i, h)) {
                                    for (int r = 0; argv[r] != NULL; r++) {
                                        dest = malloc(sizeof(char *) * strlen(argv[r]) + 1);
                                        *dest = '0';
                                        strcpy(dest, argv[r]);
                                        string[w][r] = dest;
                                    }
                                    w++;

                                } else {
                                    if (!b1) { /* no args (?) */
                                        for (int r = 0; argv[r] != NULL; r++) {
                                            string[i][r] = argv[r];
                                        }

                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    mylabel:
                    free(ptr);
                    dump_argv((const char *) "d", argc, argv);
                }
            }
            free(ptr1);
            free(cmdtmp);
            free(tmpchar);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; DEBUG && string[i][j] != NULL; j++) {
                if (i == 0 && j == 0) printf("\n");
                printf("p[%d][%d] %s\n", i, j, string[i][j]);
            }
            structcommand[i].argv = string[i];
        }
        fflush(NULL);
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
            perror("fork failed");
            return -1;
        }
        /* If we are the child process, then go execute the string.*/
        if (pid == 0) {
            /* spawn(cmd);*/
            fork_pipes(n, structcommand);
        }
        /*
         * We are the parent process.
         * Wait for the child to complete.
         */
        status = 0;
        while (((pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) < 0) && (errno == EINTR));
        if (pid < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error from waitpid: %s", strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }
        if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "pid %ld: killed by signal %d\n",
                    (long) pid, WTERMSIG(status));

            return -1;
        }
    }
    return WEXITSTATUS(status);


}

/* The shell performs wildcard expansion on each token it extracts while parsing the command line.
 * Oftentimes, globbing will obviously not do anything (for example, ls just returns ls).
 * When you want nullglob behavior you'll have to know whether the glob function actually found any glob characters, though
 */
static void expandVariable(char *shellcommand) {
    char mystring[CMD_LEN];
    char *cp;
    char *ep;

    strcpy(mystring, shellcommand);
    cp = strstr(mystring, "$(");
    if (cp) {
        *cp++ = '\0';
        strcpy(shellcommand, mystring);
        ep = ++cp;
        while (*ep && (*ep != ')')) ep++;
        if (*ep == ')') *ep++ = '\0';
        cp = getenv(cp);
        if (cp) strcat(shellcommand, cp);
        strcat(shellcommand, ep);
    }
    return;
}

int do_help(int argc, const char **argv) {
    const CommandEntry *entry;
    const char *str;

    str = NULL;

    if (argc == 2)
        str = argv[1];

    /*
     * Check for an exact match, in which case describe the program.
     */
    if (str) {
        for (entry = commandEntryTable; entry->name; entry++) {
            if (strcmp(str, entry->name) == 0) {
                printf("%s\n", entry->description);

                printf("usage: %s %s\n", entry->name,
                       entry->usage);

                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Print short information about commands which contain the
     * specified word.
     */
    for (entry = commandEntryTable; entry->name; entry++) {
        if ((str == NULL) || (strstr(entry->name, str) != NULL) ||
            (strstr(entry->usage, str) != NULL)) {
            printf("%-10s %s\n", entry->name, entry->usage);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

char s[] = "Interrupt\n";
char *input;

void handler(int signum) {
    input = '\0';
    if (write(fileno(stdin), s, sizeof s - 1)) { } else { }
    if (signum) { if (false); } else { }
}

/*
 * Try to execute a built-in command.
 * Returns TRUE if the command is a built in, whether or not the
 * command succeeds.  Returns FALSE if this is not a built-in command.
 */
bool exec_builtin(const char *cmd) {
    const char *endCmd;
    const CommandEntry *entry;
    int argc;
    const char **argv;
    char cmdName[CMD_LEN];

    /*
     * Look for the end of the command name and then copy the
     * command name to a buffer so we can null terminate it.
     */
    endCmd = cmd;

    if (endCmd)
        while (*endCmd && !isBlank(*endCmd))
            endCmd++;

    memcpy(cmdName, cmd, endCmd - cmd);
    cmdName[endCmd - cmd] = '\0';

    /*
     * Search the command table looking for the command name.
     */
    for (entry = commandEntryTable; entry->name != NULL; entry++) {
        if (strcmp(entry->name, cmdName) == 0)
            break;
    }

    /*
     * If the command is not a built-in, return indicating that.
     */
    if (entry->name == NULL) {
        return false;
    }

    bool bo = false;
    /*
     * The command is a built-in.
     * Break the command up into arguments and expand wildcards.
     */
    if (!makeArgs(cmd, &argc, &argv, bo, 0, 0)) {
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * Give a usage string if the number of arguments is too large
     * or too small.
     */
    if ((argc < entry->minArgs) || (argc > entry->maxArgs)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s %s\n", entry->name, entry->usage);
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * Call the built-in function with the argument list.
     */
    entry->func(argc, argv);
    return true;
}


/*
 * Parse and execute one null-terminated command line string.
 * This breaks the command line up into words, checks to see if the
 * command is an alias, and expands wildcards.
 */
int command(const char *cmd) {
    const char *endCmd;
    char cmdName[CMD_LEN];
    freeChunks();

    /*
     * Skip leading blanks.
     */
    if (cmd) {
        while (isBlank(*cmd))
            cmd++;
        /*
         * If the command is empty or is a comment then ignore it.
         */
        if (cmd) if ((*cmd == '\0') || (*cmd == '#'))
            return 0;
        /*
         * Look for the end of the command name and then copy the
         * command name to a buffer so we can null terminate it.
         */
        endCmd = cmd;
        if (endCmd)
            while (*endCmd && !isBlank(*endCmd))
                endCmd++;

        memcpy(cmdName, cmd, endCmd - cmd);
        cmdName[endCmd - cmd] = '\0';
        /*
         * Expand simple environment variables
         */


        if (cmd)
            while (strstr(cmd, "$("))
                expandVariable((char *) cmd);
        /*
          * Now look for the command in the builtin table, and execute
          * the command if found.
          */
        if (exec_builtin(cmd)) {
            return 0;
        }
        /*
         * The command is not a built-in, so run the program along
         * the PATH list.
         */
        return runCmd(cmd);
    }
    else return 0;
}

void getPath() {
    if (getenv("PATH") == NULL) {
        printf("'%s' is not set.\n", "PATH");
        /* Default our path if it is not set. */
        putenv("PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/etc");
    }
    else if (getenv("PATH")) {
        printf("'%s' is set to %s.\n", "PATH", (getenv("PATH")));
    }
}

char *prompt(EditLine *e) {
    static char p2[] = "\1\033[36m$ \033[0m\1";
    static char p[] = "$ ";
    return p;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct sigaction sh;
    /* char *shell_prompt[100];*/
    sh.sa_handler = handler;
    sigemptyset(&sh.sa_mask);
    sh.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sh, NULL);
    int index = 0;
    int i;
    /*  EditLine *el = el_init(argv[0], stdin, stdout, stderr);
      el_set(el, EL_PROMPT_ESC, &prompt, '\1');
      el_set(el, EL_EDITOR, "emacs");
      el_set(el, EL_BIND, "bind ^I el_complete");*/
    rl_bind_key('\t', rl_complete);
    /*rl_parse_and_bind("bind ^I rl_complete");*/

    /*rl_bind_key('\t', rl_complete);*/
    HistEvent ev;
    History *myhistory;
    while (1) {
        index = 0;
        i = getopt_long(argc, argv, "p:vh",
                        options, &index);
        if (i == -1)
            break;
        switch (i) {
            case 'p': {
                /* store_parameter(optarg); */
                break;
            }
            case 'v': {
                printf("OpenShell version 0.1(a)\n");
                printf("Version: %s\n", VERSION);
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

            }
            case 'h': {
                printf("Usage: ./shell\n");
                /*print_help();*/
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

            }
            default: {
                /* fprintf(stderr, "Error (%s): unrecognized option.\n", __FUNCTION__);*/
                /* print_help();*/
                return 1;/*RETURN_FAILURE;*/

            }
        }
    }
    getPath();

    char *shell_prompt;
    for (; ;) {
        shell_prompt = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 1024);
        snprintf(shell_prompt, sizeof(shell_prompt), "%s: $ ", getenv("USER"));
        input = readline(shell_prompt);
        if (input)
            add_history(input);
        command(input);
        free(input);
        free(shell_prompt);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

### util.c

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500

#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "errors.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "openshell.h"

/*
struct command {
    char *const *argv;
};*/
static CHUNK *chunkList;


/*
 * Free all chunks of memory that had been allocated since the last
 * call to this routine.
 */
void freeChunks(void) {
    CHUNK *chunk;

    while (chunkList) {
        chunk = chunkList;
        chunkList = chunk->next;
        free((char *) chunk);
    }
}

/*
 * Allocate a chunk of memory (like malloc).
 * The difference, though, is that the memory allocated is put on a
 * list of chunks which can be freed all at one time.  You CAN NOT free
 * an individual chunk.
 */
char *getChunk(int size) {
    CHUNK *chunk;

    if (size < CHUNK_INIT_SIZE)
        size = CHUNK_INIT_SIZE;

    chunk = (CHUNK *) malloc(size + sizeof(CHUNK) - CHUNK_INIT_SIZE);

    if (chunk == NULL)
        return NULL;

    chunk->next = chunkList;
    chunkList = chunk;

    return chunk->data;
}

bool find_less_program(char *path) {

    bool found = false;
    char *curr_path;
    const char program[] = "/less";

    while (path && !found) {
        if ((curr_path = malloc(strlen(path) + sizeof(program))) != NULL) {

            strcpy(curr_path, path);
            strcat(curr_path, program);
            if (file_exist(curr_path)) {
                found = true; // we found the program
            }
            free(curr_path);
            path = strtok(NULL, ":");
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed!\n");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return found;
}

/* Sort routine for list of fileNames.
*/
int nameSort(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    const char **s1;
    const char **s2;

    s1 = (const char **) p1;
    s2 = (const char **) p2;

    return strcmp(*s1, *s2);
}


/* Routine to see if a text string is matched by a wildcard pattern.
* Returns true if the text is matched, or false if it is not matched
* or if the pattern is invalid.
*  *        matches zero or more characters
*  ?        matches a single character
*  [abc]    matches 'a', 'b' or 'c'
*  \c       quotes character c
*  Adapted from code written by Ingo Wilken.
*/
bool
match(const char *text, const char *pattern) {
    const char *retryPat;
    const char *retryText;
    int ch;
    bool found;

    retryPat = NULL;
    retryText = NULL;

    while (*text || *pattern) {
        ch = *pattern++;

        switch (ch) {
            case '*':
                retryPat = pattern;
                retryText = text;
                break;

            case '[':
                found = 0;

                while ((ch = *pattern++) != ']') {
                    if (ch == '\\')
                        ch = *pattern++;

                    if (ch == '\0')
                        return 0;

                    if (*text == ch)
                        found = 1;
                }

                if (!found) {
                    pattern = retryPat;
                    text = ++retryText;
                }

                /* fall into next case */

            case '?':
                if (*text++ == '\0')
                    return 0;

                break;

            case '\\':
                ch = *pattern++;

                if (ch == '\0')
                    return 0;

                /* fall into next case */

            default:
                if (*text == ch) {
                    if (*text)
                        text++;
                    break;
                }

                if (*text) {
                    pattern = retryPat;
                    text = ++retryText;
                    break;
                }

                return 0;
        }

        if (pattern == NULL)
            return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

/* This will replace all occurrence of "str" with "rep" in "src"... */
void strreplace(char *src, char *str, char *rep) {
    char *p = strstr(src, str);
    do {
        if (p) {
            char buf[1024];
            memset(buf, '\0', strlen(buf));

            if (src == p) {
                strcpy(buf, rep);
                strcat(buf, p + strlen(str));
            }
            else {
                strncpy(buf, src, strlen(src) - strlen(p));
                strcat(buf, rep);
                strcat(buf, p + strlen(str));
            }

            memset(src, '\0', strlen(src));
            strcpy(src, buf);
        }

    } while (p && (p = strstr(src, str)));
}

char **str_split(char *a[], char *a_str, const char a_delim) {
    char **result = 0;
    size_t count = 0;
    char *tmp = a_str;
    char *last_comma = 0;
    char delim[2];
    delim[0] = a_delim;
    delim[1] = 0;

    /* Count how many elements will be extracted. */
    while (*tmp) {
        if (a_delim == *tmp) {
            count++;
            last_comma = tmp;
        }
        tmp++;
    }

    /* Add space for trailing token. */
    count += last_comma < (a_str + strlen(a_str) - 1);

    /* Add space for terminating null string so caller
       knows where the list of returned strings ends. */
    count++;

    result = malloc(sizeof(char *) * count);
    if (result == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory!\n"); //print an error message
        return result; //return with failure
    }

    if (result) {
        size_t idx = 0;
        char *token = strtok(a_str, delim);

        while (token) {
            assert(idx < count);
            *(result + idx++) = strdup(token);
            token = strtok(0, delim);
        }
        assert(idx == count - 1);
        *(result + idx) = 0;
    }

    return result;
}

/* Expand the wildcards in a fileName wildcard pattern, if any.
* Returns an argument list with matching fileNames in sorted order.
* The expanded names are stored in memory chunks which can later all
* be freed at once.  The returned list is only valid until the next
        * call or until the next command.  Returns zero if the name is not a
        * wildcard, or returns the count of matched files if the name is a
* wildcard and there was at least one match, or returns -1 if either
        * no fileNames matched or there was an allocation error.
*/
int expandWildCards(const char *fileNamePattern, const char ***retFileTable) {
    const char *last;
    const char *cp1;
    const char *cp2;
    const char *cp3;
    const char *possible_tilde;
    char *str;
    DIR *dirp;
    struct dirent *dp;
    unsigned long dirLen;
    int newFileTableSize;
    char **newFileTable;
    char dirName[PATH_LEN];
    char *path;
    static int fileCount;
    static int fileTableSize;
    static char **fileTable;

    /*
     * Clear the return values until we know their final values.
     */
    fileCount = 0;
    *retFileTable = NULL;

    /*
     * Scan the file name pattern for any wildcard characters.
     */
    cp1 = strchr(fileNamePattern, '*');
    cp2 = strchr(fileNamePattern, '?');
    cp3 = strchr(fileNamePattern, '[');

    /*
 * Scan the file name pattern for tilde
 */
    possible_tilde = strchr(fileNamePattern, '~');
    if (possible_tilde != NULL) {
        path = getenv("HOME");
        if (path == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "No HOME environment variable\n");
            return 1;
        }
        strreplace((char *) fileNamePattern, "~", path);
    }

    /*
     * If there are no wildcard characters then return zero to
     * indicate that there was actually no wildcard pattern.
     */
    if ((cp1 == NULL) && (cp2 == NULL) && (cp3 == NULL) && (possible_tilde == NULL))
        return 0;

    /*
     * There are wildcards in the specified filename.
     * Get the last component of the file name.
     */
    last = strrchr(fileNamePattern, '/');

    if (last)
        last++;
    else
        last = fileNamePattern;

    /*
     * If any wildcards were found before the last filename component
     * then return an error.
     */
    if ((cp1 && (cp1 < last)) || (cp2 && (cp2 < last)) ||
        (cp3 && (cp3 < last))) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "Wildcards only implemented for last file name component\n");

        return -1;
    }

    /*
     * Assume at first that we are scanning the current directory.
     */
    dirName[0] = '.';
    dirName[1] = '\0';

    /*
     * If there was a directory given as part of the file name then
     * copy it and null terminate it.
     */
    if (last != fileNamePattern) {
        memcpy(dirName, fileNamePattern, last - fileNamePattern);
        dirName[last - fileNamePattern - 1] = '\0';

        if (dirName[0] == '\0') {
            dirName[0] = '/';
            dirName[1] = '\0';
        }
    }

    /*
     * Open the directory containing the files to be checked.
     */
    dirp = opendir(dirName);

    if (dirp == NULL) {
        perror(dirName);
        return -1;
    }

    /*
     * Prepare the directory name for use in making full path names.
     */
    dirLen = strlen(dirName);

    if (last == fileNamePattern) {
        dirLen = 0;
        dirName[0] = '\0';
    }
    else if (dirName[dirLen - 1] != '/') {
        dirName[dirLen++] = '/';
        dirName[dirLen] = '\0';
    }

    /*
     * Find all of the files in the directory and check them against
     * the wildcard pattern.
     */
    while ((dp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
        /*
         * Skip the current and parent directories.
         */
        if ((strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") == 0) ||
            (strcmp(dp->d_name, "..") == 0)) {
            continue;
        }

        /*
         * If the file name doesn't match the pattern then skip it.
         */
        if (!match(dp->d_name, last))
            continue;

        /*
         * This file name is selected.
         * See if we need to reallocate the file name table.
         */
        if (fileCount >= fileTableSize) {
            /*
             * Increment the file table size and reallocate it.
             */
            newFileTableSize = fileTableSize + EXPAND_ALLOC;

            newFileTable = (char **) realloc((char *) fileTable,
                                             (newFileTableSize * sizeof(char *)));

            if (newFileTable == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate file list\n");
                closedir(dirp);
                return -1;
            }
            fileTable = newFileTable;
            fileTableSize = newFileTableSize;
        }

        /*
         * Allocate space for storing the file name in a chunk.
         */
        str = getChunk((int) dirLen + (int) strlen(dp->d_name) + 1);

        if (str == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "No memory for file name\n");
            closedir(dirp);
            return -1;
        }

        /*
         * Save the file name in the chunk.
         */
        if (dirLen) {
            memcpy(str, dirName, dirLen);
        }
        strcpy(str + dirLen, dp->d_name);
        /*
             * Save the allocated file name into the file table.
             */
        fileTable[fileCount++] = str;

    }
    /*
     * Close the directory and check for any matches.
     */
    closedir(dirp);

    if (fileCount == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No matches\n");

        /*  for(int i=0;i<fileCount;i++) {
              printf("fileTable %d %s", fileCount, fileTable[i]);
          }*/
        return -1;
    }

    /*
     * Sort the list of file names.
     */
    qsort((void *) fileTable, (size_t) fileCount, sizeof(char *), nameSort);

    /*
     * Return the file list and count.
     */
    *retFileTable = (const char **) fileTable;

    return fileCount;
}

int do_checkenv(int argc, const char **argv) {
    int status;
    int len = 1;
    char *grep[4];
    char *tmp;
    int k;
    char *pagerValue;
    int pos = 0;
    int i = 0;
    struct command shellcommand[4];
    char *pager_cmd[] = {"less", 0};
    char *printenv[] = {"printenv", 0};
    char *sort[] = {"sort", 0};
    char *path_strdup;
    char *path_value;
    char *pathValue;
    pid_t pid;
    pathValue = getenv("PATH");
    path_strdup = strdup(pathValue);
    path_value = strtok(path_strdup, ":");
    if (find_less_program(path_value)) {
        pager_cmd[0] = "less";
    }
    pagerValue = getenv("PAGER");
    if (!pagerValue) {
        if (find_less_program(path_value)) {
            pager_cmd[0] = "less";
        } else {
            pager_cmd[0] = "more";
        }
    }
    else {
        pager_cmd[0] = pagerValue;
    }

    if (i == 1) {
        /* do nothing */
    }
    else {
        for (k = 1; k < i; k++) {
            len += strlen(argv[k]) + 2;
        }
        tmp = (char *) malloc(len);
        tmp[0] = '\0';
        for (k = 1; k < argc; k++) {
            pos += sprintf(tmp + pos, "%s%s", (k == 1 ? "" : "|"), argv[k]);
        }
        printf("tmp %s", tmp);
        grep[0] = "grep";
        grep[1] = "-E";
        grep[2] = tmp;
        grep[3] = NULL;
        shellcommand[0].argv = printenv;
        shellcommand[1].argv = grep;
        shellcommand[2].argv = sort;
        shellcommand[3].argv = pager_cmd;
        fflush(NULL);
        pid = fork();

        if (pid < 0) {
            perror("fork failed");

            return -1;
        }

        if (pid == 0) {
            fork_pipes(4, shellcommand);

        }
        /*
            * We are the parent process.
            * Wait for the child to complete.
            */
        status = 0;

        while (((pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) < 0) && (errno == EINTR));

        if (pid < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error from waitpid: %s", strerror(errno));

            return -1;
        }

        if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "pid %ld: killed by signal %d\n",
                    (long) pid, WTERMSIG(status));

            return -1;
        }

        return WEXITSTATUS(status);

    }
    return 1;
}

int do_editenv(int argc, const char **argv) {
    int r = 0;

    if (getpid() == 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "You are the INIT process!\n");

        return 1;
    }

    if (argc == 2) {
        r = atoi(argv[1]);
    }

    exit(r);

    return 1;
}

int do_cd(int argc, const char **argv) {
    const char *path;
    if (argc > 1) {
        path = argv[1];
    }
    else {
        path = getenv("HOME");
        if (path == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "No HOME environment variable\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (chdir(path) < 0) {
        perror(path);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int do_exit(int argc, const char **argv) {
    int r = 0;

    if (getpid() == 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "You are the INIT process!\n");

        return 1;
    }

    if (argc == 2) {
        r = atoi(argv[1]);
    }

    exit(r);

    return 1;
}


int do_killport(int argc, const char **argv) {

    return 0;
}

/*
 * Take a command string and break it up into an argc, argv list while
 * handling quoting and wildcards.  The returned argument list and
 * strings are in static memory, and so are overwritten on each call.
 * The argument list is ended with a NULL pointer for convenience.
 * Returns true if successful, or false on an error with a message
 * already output.
 */
bool makeArgs(const char *cmd, int *retArgc, const char ***retArgv, bool pipe, int g, int h) {
    const char *argument;
    char *cp;
    char *cpOut;
    char *newStrings;
    const char **fileTable;
    const char **newArgTable;
    int newArgTableSize;
    int fileCount;
    int len;
    int ch;
    int quote;
    bool quotedWildCards;
    bool unquotedWildCards;
    bool tilde;
    static int stringsLength;
    static char *strings;
    static int argCount;
    static int argTableSize;
    static const char **argTable;
    /*
     * Clear the returned values until we know them.
     */
    argCount = 0;
    *retArgc = 0;
    *retArgv = NULL;
    tilde = false;
    /*
     * Copy the command string into a buffer that we can modify,
     * reallocating it if necessary.
     */
    len = strlen(cmd) + 1;

    if (len > stringsLength) {
        newStrings = realloc(strings, len);

        if (newStrings == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate string\n");

            return false;
        }

        strings = newStrings;
        stringsLength = len;
    }

    memcpy(strings, cmd, len);
    cp = strings;

    /*
     * Keep parsing the command string as long as there are any
     * arguments left.
     */
    while (*cp) {
        /*
         * Save the beginning of this argument.
         */
        argument = cp;
        cpOut = cp;

        /*
         * Reset quoting and wildcarding for this argument.
         */
        quote = '\0';
        quotedWildCards = false;
        unquotedWildCards = false;

        /*
         * Loop over the string collecting the next argument while
         * looking for quoted strings or quoted characters, and
         * remembering whether there are any wildcard characters
         * in the argument.
         */
        while (*cp) {
            ch = *cp++;
            /*       if (ch == '|') {
                       *cpOut++ = '|';
                       printf("** deal with it **%s", argument);
                       char *tmpchar = malloc(sizeof(argument));
                       strcpy(tmpchar, argument);
                       char *command[40];
                       tokens = cp;
       */

            /*++tokens = "\0";*
           ;//str_split(command, tmpchar, '|');*/
            /*              calc = 1;
                          continue;*
                      }*/

            /*
             * If we are not in a quote and we see a blank or a pipeline char then
             * this argument is done.
             */
            if (isBlank(ch) && (quote == '\0'))

                break;


            /* check for tilde */

            if (ch == '~') {
                tilde = true;
            }

            /*
             * If we see a backslash then accept the next
             * character no matter what it is.
             */
            if (ch == '\\') {
                ch = *cp++;

                /*
                 * Make sure there is a next character.
                 */
                if (ch == '\0') {
                    fprintf(stderr,
                            "Bad quoted character\n");

                    return false;
                }

                /*
                 * Remember whether the quoted character
                 * is a wildcard.
                 */
                if (isWildCard(ch))
                    quotedWildCards = true;

                *cpOut++ = ch;

                continue;
            }

            /*
             * If we see one of the wildcard characters then
             * remember whether it was seen inside or outside
             * of quotes.
             */
            if (isWildCard(ch)) {
                if (quote)
                    quotedWildCards = true;
                else
                    unquotedWildCards = true;
            }

            /*
             * If we were in a quote and we saw the same quote
             * character again then the quote is done.
             */
            if (ch == quote) {
                quote = '\0';

                continue;
            }

            /*
             * If we weren't in a quote and we see either type
             * of quote character, then remember that we are
             * now inside of a quote.
             */
            if ((quote == '\0') && ((ch == '\'') || (ch == '"'))) {
                quote = ch;

                continue;
            }

            /*
             * Store the character.
             */
            *cpOut++ = ch;
        }

        /*
         * Make sure that quoting is terminated properly.
         */
        if (quote) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unmatched quote character\n");

            return false;
        }

        /*
         * Null terminate the argument if it had shrunk, and then
         * skip over all blanks to the next argument, nulling them
         * out too.
         */
        if (cp != cpOut)
            *cpOut = '\0';

        while (isBlank(*cp))
            *cp++ = '\0';

        /*
         * If both quoted and unquoted wildcards were used then
         * complain since we don't handle them properly.
         */
        if (quotedWildCards && unquotedWildCards) {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    "Cannot use quoted and unquoted wildcards\n");

            return false;
        }

        if (tilde) {
            /*
             * Expand the argument into the matching filenames.
             */
            fileCount = expandWildCards(argument, &fileTable);

        }

        /*
         * Expand the argument into the matching filenames or accept
         * it as is depending on whether there were any unquoted
         * wildcard characters in it.
         */
        if (unquotedWildCards) {
            /*
             * Expand the argument into the matching filenames.
             */
            fileCount = expandWildCards(argument, &fileTable);

            /*
             * Return an error if the wildcards failed to match.
             */
            if (fileCount < 0)
                return false;

            if (fileCount == 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Wildcard expansion error\n");

                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            /*
             * Set up to only store the argument itself.
             */
            fileTable = &argument;
            fileCount = 1;

        }

        /*
         * Now reallocate the argument table to hold the file name.
         */
        if (argCount + fileCount >= argTableSize) {
            newArgTableSize = argCount + fileCount + 1;

            newArgTable = (const char **) realloc(argTable,
                                                  (sizeof(const char *) * newArgTableSize));

            if (newArgTable == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "No memory for arg list\n");

                return false;
            }

            argTable = newArgTable;
            argTableSize = newArgTableSize;

        }

        if (1) {


/*            for(int i=0;i<argCount;i++){
            }*/

            /*
             * Copy the new arguments to the end of the old ones.
             */

            /*  copy_of_argv = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (argTableSize+fileCount));*/
            /*    memcpy(copy_of_argv,argTable, fileCount*sizeof(const char **));*/

            /*  int q;
              char **copy_of_argv = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (argc-1));
              for (q = 0; q < argc - 1; q++) {
                  copy_of_argv[q] = strdup(argv[q + 1]);
              }
  */

            memcpy((void *) &argTable[argCount], (const void *) fileTable,
                   (sizeof(const char **) * fileCount));

            /*   int i;
               copy_of_argv = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (argTableSize-1));
               for (i = 0; i < argCount - 1; i++) {
                   copy_of_argv[i] = strdup(argTable[i + 1]);
               }
   */

            /*  if (tokens) {
                  int count = argCount + 1;
                  memcpy((void *) &argTable[argCount], (const void *) tokens,
                         (sizeof(const char **) * 20));
                  tokens = NULL;


              }*/

            /*
         * Add to the argument count.
         */
            argCount += fileCount;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Null terminate the argument list and return it.
     */
    if (tilde) --argCount;

    argTable[argCount] = NULL;
    *retArgc = argCount;
    *retArgv = argTable;

    return true;
}
/*

int isBetweenQuotes(int pos, char *str) {
    return IBQplain(pos, str, 0);
}
int IBQsingle(int pos, char *str, int offset) {
    int escaped = 0;
    for (; str[offset]; ++offset) {
        if (!escaped) {
            switch (str[offset]) {
                case '\\':
                    escaped = 1;
                case '\'':
                    return IBQplain(pos, str, offset + 1);
            }
        } else {
            escaped = 0;
        }
        if (pos == offset) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

int IBQdouble(int pos, char *str, int offset) {
    int escaped = 0;
    for (; str[offset]; ++offset) {
        if (!escaped) {
            switch (str[offset]) {
                case '\\':
                    escaped = 1;
                case '"':
                    return IBQdouble(pos, str, offset + 1);
            }
        } else {
            escaped = 0;
        }
        if (pos == offset) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

int IBQplain(int pos, char *str, int offset) {
    char ch;
    if (pos == offset)
        return 0;  // Not within quotes
    int escaped = 0;
    for (ch = str[offset]; ch; ch = str[++offset]) {
        if (!escaped) {
            switch (str[offset]) {
                '\'': return IBQsingle(pos, str, offset + 1);
                '"':  return IBQdouble(pos, str, offset + 1);
                '\\': escaped = 1
            } else {
                escaped = 0;
            }
            if (pos == offset)
                return escaped;  // Not within quotes, but may be single-escaped
        }
    }
}
*/
/* Helper function that spawns processes */
int spawn_proc(int in, int out, struct command *cmd) {
    pid_t pid;
    fflush(NULL);
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        if (in != 0) {
            if (dup2(in, 0) < 0)
                err_syserr("dup2() failed on stdin for %s: ", cmd->argv[0]);
            close(in);
        }
        if (out != 1) {
            if (dup2(out, 1) < 0)
                err_syserr("dup2() failed on stdout for %s: ", cmd->argv[0]);
            close(out);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: executing %s\n", (int) getpid(), cmd->argv[0]);
        execvp(cmd->argv[0], cmd->argv);
        err_syserr("failed to execute %s: ", cmd->argv[0]);
    }
    else if (pid < 0) {
        err_syserr("fork failed: ");
    } else {
        /* printf("** we are the parent ***"); */
    }
    return pid;
}

/* Helper function that forks pipes */
void fork_pipes(int n, struct command *cmd) {
    int i;
    int in = 0;
    int fd[2];

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {

        if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
            err_syserr("Failed creating pipe");
        }

        spawn_proc(in, fd[1], cmd + i);
        close(fd[1]);
        in = fd[0];
    }
    if (dup2(in, 0) < 0) {
        err_syserr("dup2() failed on stdin for %s: ", cmd[i].argv[0]);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "%d: executing %s\n", (int) getpid(), cmd[i].argv[0]);
    execvp(cmd[i].argv[0], cmd[i].argv);
    err_syserr("failed to execute %s: ", cmd[i].argv[0]);
}

/* helper function that determines whether a file exists */
int file_exist(char *filename) {
    struct stat buffer;
    return (stat(filename, &buffer) == 0);
}

void handle_sigchld(int sig) {
    int saved_errno = errno;
    while (waitpid((pid_t) (-1), 0, WNOHANG) > 0) { }
    errno = saved_errno;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with your runCmd method, that is one of the most unreadable methods I have ever seen and it CRIES to be broken up into several methods at least. Start with giving **each variable a meaningful name**, then **break up** as much as you can into sub methods to reduce the depth. As a general guideline, two nested control flow statements are already hard to read.

Comment: I think I'm going to break out the for loops to become their own functions. I agree it is unreadable.

Answer (score 3):

#### Method decomposition

The `runCmd` function starts with ~30 lines of variable declarations.
This is a clear sign that the function is doing too many things and need to be split to smaller functions.

#### Magic numbers

What is number 75 in this code?

> ```
> for (int x = 0; x < 75; x++) { /* for each pipeline */
>     for (int c = 0; c < 75; c++) { /* for each pipeline */
>         string[x][c] = '\0';
>     }
> }
> ```

It's really not clear what this is and why it has this specific value.
A good way to clarify that is to put in a variable or macro definition with a descriptive name.

#### Pointless code

This block of code seems completely pointless:

> ```
>     for (cp = cmd; *cp; cp++) {
>         if ((*cp >= 'a') && (*cp <= 'z')) {
>             continue;
>         }
>         if ((*cp >= 'A') && (*cp <= 'Z')) {
>             continue;
>         }
>         if (isDecimal(*cp)) {
>             continue;
>         }
>         if (isBlank(*cp)) {
>             continue;
>         }
>         if ((*cp == '.') || (*cp == '/') || (*cp == '-') ||
>             (*cp == '+') || (*cp == '=') || (*cp == '_') ||
>             (*cp == ':') || (*cp == ',') || (*cp == '\'') ||
>             (*cp == '"')) {
>             continue;
>         }
>     }
> ```

Did you forget to implement something inside that loop after all the conditions?

---

What is going on here?

> ```
> void handler(int signum) {
>     input = '\0';
>     if (write(fileno(stdin), s, sizeof s - 1)) { } else { }
>     if (signum) { if (false); } else { }
> }
> ```

`input` is a global variable. Why update its value here? At the minimum a comment would be nice explaining the reason. Ideally you should avoid global variables altogether.

If we remove the code that does nothing, the function becomes:

```
void handler(int signum) {
    input = '\0';
    write(fileno(stdin), s, sizeof s - 1));
}
```

---

In this code, the variable `bo` is pointless, it doesn't have a name that tells the reader anything, so you can just as well use its value directly inside the `makeArgs` call.

> ```
> bool bo = false;
> /*
>  * The command is a built-in.
>  * Break the command up into arguments and expand wildcards.
>  */
> if (!makeArgs(cmd, &argc, &argv, bo, 0, 0)) {
>     return true;
> }
> ```

#### Simplify boolean expression

Instead of this:

> ```
> return (str && *str && str[strlen(str) - 1] == '}') ? 1 : 0;
> ```

You can write simply:

```
return str && *str && str[strlen(str) - 1] == '}';
```

And change the return type of the function from `int` to `bool`.

#### Use braces always

Instead of this:

> ```
> if (endCmd)
>     while (*endCmd && !isBlank(*endCmd))
>         endCmd++;
> ```

The recommended writing style is to always use braces:

```
if (endCmd) {
    while (*endCmd && !isBlank(*endCmd)) {
        endCmd++;
    }
}
```